# EDI ANSI X12 204 SEF file

Tags: edi, x12

I am looking for EDI x12 4010-204 **SEF** file. Please let me know where can find this file.

Actually, I need the details of all the EDI-204 segments and there corresponding qualifiers. Please help me if anyone knows where can I find this.

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Why do you need the SEF file?  These are becoming increasingly rare with implementation guidelines and sample transactions so prevalent.  A link to Liaison's dictionary viewer: http://www.liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad/edi-dictionary-viewer/   and a link to a SEF file example (but you need to download their free reader): http://edidev.com/eval_SefFile.html

Answer (score 0):

A similar question arose from someone dealing with Amazon.  I strongly suggest you reach out to your trading partner for their standards -- this is the normal behavior in the EDI world.  Since EDI provides general guidelines, but the actual implementation within even a single transaction like the 850 (purchase order), varies widely from customer to customer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't technically need a SEF file. In our case, we went straight to the in-house developed solution path by writing our own classes and programs to translate EDIFACT messages into XML and then capturing the data we needed into SQL Server tables.
First you need to determine what data you want out of the EDI message. Next, you need to translate the message into a readable format such as XML (the SEF file is a map of the EDI which is why you think you need it. Yes it helps but it's not mandatory). Once you have it translated, then you can extract what you need.
I strongly suggest you read and study this great effort in CodeProject...
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11278/EDIFACT-to-XML-to-Anything-You-Want
Remember, EDI files are really a "message packet" and are not files that one would convert into another file such as CSV or even XML. You need to firstly "map" the EDI message into a meaningful layout that you can then "pull out" data from, to meet your needs.
Think of EDI as being the precursor to BLOCKCHAIN. Yes, Bitcoin. Remember that!? Blockchain is the modern version of EDI messaging and Business-2-Business processing.